# Deploying Nodejs Express js App on heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my app on heroku, but I'm always getting this error

```
2022-08-11T12:49:12.131468+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
2022-08-11T12:49:12.131469+00:00 app[web.1]: at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1247:16) {
2022-08-11T12:49:12.131470+00:00 app[web.1]: errno: -111,
2022-08-11T12:49:12.131470+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
2022-08-11T12:49:12.131470+00:00 app[web.1]: syscall: 'connect',
2022-08-11T12:49:12.131471+00:00 app[web.1]: address: '127.0.0.1',
2022-08-11T12:49:12.131471+00:00 app[web.1]: port: 3306,
2022-08-11T12:49:12.131471+00:00 app[web.1]: fatal: true
2022-08-11T12:49:12.131472+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2022-08-11T12:49:12.131494+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-08-11T12:49:12.131494+00:00 app[web.1]: Node.js v18.7.0
```

Could anybody help me solve this problem?
This is the server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

const filterByDateRouter = require('./routes/filterByDate');
const filterByLogsRouter = require('./routes/filterByLogs');
const mainPageRouter = require('./routes/index'); 

app.use("/filterByDate", filterByDateRouter)
app.use("/filterByLogs", filterByLogsRouter)
app.use("/",mainPageRouter)
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/css'))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/js'))


app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000)
```

this is the database connection:

```
var connection = mysql.createPool({
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  connectionLimit:10,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
});
```

I'm using clearMYSQL from heroku to deploy my database, and all the fields saved in the .env are right

Comment: You are using the wrong environment variables. _"all the fields saved in the .env are right"_ Why are you so sure?

Comment: What exactly makes you think that the environment variables are wrong? Let me understand pls!

Comment: The line `2022-08-11T12:49:12.131468+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306` makes me think that `DB_HOST` is either not set or contains the wrong value. `127.0.0.1:3306` is the default value.

Comment: You have to retrieve all the necessary values from `CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL`. In PHP you can use [`parse_url`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php). I don't know the corresponding JavaScript function.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the `CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL` and parse it:

```
const url = new URL(process.env.CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL);
const host = url.hostname;
const port = url.port || 3306;
const user = url.username;
const password = url.password;
const database = url.pathname.substring(1);
const connection = mysql.createPool({
  host,
  user,
  password,
  connectionLimit:10,
  database,
  port
});
```

Comment: Does this have to be in the server.js? Because I have a folder called "models" and inside that there is my database.js. In there, I have all the connection and functions I have to use in order to get or post informations from/in the database

Comment: @kRYstall9 No, you can put it whereever you want.

Comment: Perfect. You're a life saver! I solved my problem copying your above code. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

You can also add your enviroment variables that are provided by hosting providers. You can also add env variables in heroku from settings>Config Vars

[image: 1]